# CakePHP3 Plugin cell is missing

Tags: cell, cakephp-3.1

My Process

1. **make plugin cell**

   ```
   $ bin/cake bake plugin Abc

   $ bin/cake bake cell Abc.New
   ```

upper process make 3 files

```
    plugins/Abc/src/View/Cell/NewCell.php

    plugins/Abc/src/Template/Cell/Menu/display.php
```

and test file.

2. **insert layout/default.ctp next code**

   ```
    <?php $cell = $this->cell('Abc.New'); ?>
   ```
3. ***error***

> Cell class Abc.New is missing.
>
> Cake\View\Exception\MissingCellException

I can't find solution. please help me!!

Comment: did you load your plugin?

Comment: ^^ of course~  Plugin::loadAll();

Answer (score 2):

Post is a bit old but in case someone else stumbles on this thread...

Cells rely on Namespaces to load and render the correct [cell].ctp file. In other words, even though you have done the required `Plugin::loadAll();` in your bootstrap.php file, you still need to modify the composer.json file and add the Plugin. For example, my Plugin is called 'Metronic', notice the extra 2 lines in `autoload` and `autolaod-dev`

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src",
      "Metronic\\": "./plugins/Metronic/src"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Test\\": "tests",
      "Cake\\Test\\": "./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests",
      "Metronic\\Test\\": "./plugins/Metronic/tests"
    }
  },
```

See CakePHP manual here http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#autoloading-plugin-classes.

My suggestions is that you use the Bake command to create Plugins in the future. The manual does not explicitly say this, but this is what happens when you use the Bake command:

- It creates the basic directory structure for the Plugin
- It inserts a line in bootstrap.php e.g.`Plugin::load('Metronic', ['bootstrap' => false, 'routes' => true]);`
- It inserts 2 lines in the composer.json file (as per my example above)

The only thing you need to then do is tell Composer to refresh its autoloading cache

```
$ bin\cake bake plugin Metronic
$ php composer.phar dumpautoload
```

Hope this helps..